# Download multiple files from SFTP using perl Net::SFTP::Foreign

Tags: perl

I am using the below code to download files from SFTP and I am getting error message after one file download. Then I am rerunning the program and then it downloads only one file again and when trying to download the next file in the array it get failed. I couldn't understand the reasons for this failure and kindly review the below code and share opinions.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Net::SFTP::Foreign::Constants qw(:error :status);
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
use Net::SFTP::Foreign::Attributes;


my $SFTP_CON=Net::SFTP::Foreign->new("sftpserver.test.com",user=>"testuser",password=>"pass");
my @SFTP_Files=('/test/1.txt','/test/2.txt','/test/3.txt');
my $root_dir='/test/';
$local_dir='/u/test/';

foreach my $file_to_dwn(@SFTP_Files){
    my $file_to=$file_to_dwn;
    $file_to=~s/$root_dir/$local_dir/igs;

    unless($SFTP_CON->get("$file_to_dwn","$file_to")){
     if (($SFTP_CON->error == SFTP_ERR_REMOTE_STAT_FAILED or
      $SFTP_CON->error == SFTP_ERR_REMOTE_OPEN_FAILED) and
      $SFTP_CON->status == SSH2_FX_NO_SUCH_FILE) {
      print  "Remote file does not exist!";
      exit;
      }
      else {
       print "Transfer Failed";
       exit;
      }
       print $SFTP_CON->error."\n";
       exit;
      }
}
```

I am getting "Transfer Failed", when the program tries to download the one after another (second file download).

Please do needful.

Comment: Remove the `else` part and check the error reported.

Comment: I have commented the else part and files are downloading with 0 bytes. It seems the files are not transferred properly after the first instance.

No error/exception thrown.

Comment: You could try reading the module's documentation on [error handling](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#Error-handling). In particular, replacing `print "Transfer Failed"` with `$sftp->die_on_error("Transfer Failed")` looks like a good idea.

Comment: @DaveCross: That's what removing the `else` part should achieve.

Comment: @choroba: True. But given the OP's rather cavalier approach to indentation, I'd rather start by making smaller changes.

Comment: @DaveCross: Yes, I had to reindent the code in my editor before I was able to comment.

Comment: I am getting the below exception after one file download and after the line $sftp->die_on_error("Transfer Failed") updated. 

"Transfer Failed: Couldn't read from remote file: java.lang.Exception: Failed to initialize transfer directory object"

Comment: Enable debugging for Net::SFTP::Foreign and include the output you get in your post: `$Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug = (~(8|16|1024|2048));`